# how about css class prescedence in javafx

Tags: css, javafx, operator-precedence

I want to add another css class for my component by example

```
.item{
-fx-background-color:blue;
-fx-border-radius:5;
}
.item-some{
-fx-background-color:red;
}
```

and in my code

```
control.getStyleClass().addAll("item","item-some");
```

but my control only get "item-some" style i want override only the color applying the second class as in css on web, can someone help me or give me a link to read about it?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This basically behaves as expected for me: the item with both style classes gets the properties defined for both selectors. If there are conflicts, such as `fx-background-color` in this example, the one defined later in the css file overrides the ones before it.

Here's a complete test:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MultipleStyleClassTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Region region1 = new Region();
        Region region2 = new Region();
        region1.getStyleClass().add("style-class-1");
        region2.getStyleClass().addAll("style-class-1", "style-class-2");

        HBox root = new HBox(region1, region2);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("multiple-style-class-test.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

`multiple-style-class-test.css` is

```
.style-class-1 {
    -fx-min-width: 300 ;
    -fx-min-height: 400 ;
    -fx-background-color: blue ;
    -fx-background-radius: 25 ;
}

.style-class-2 {
    -fx-background-color: red ;
}
```

and the result is

[image]

As can be seen, both `region1` and `region2` get the `-fx-min-height`, `-fx-min-width`, and `-fx-background-radius` properties defined for `style-class-1`. `region1` gets the `-fx-background-color` defined for `style-class-1`; `region2` displays the background color defined for `style-class-2`.